# passar variavel por referencia entre função em c

Tags: c, funções, passagem-por-referência

> 1) Crie um programa que tenha um vetor de caracteres. Esse vetor deve ter um tamanho máximo
>   TAM = 10. Nenhum parâmetro pode ser global.
>
> O programa deve ter:
>
> a. a função main, responsável por interagir com o usuário, informando os resultados das operações das demais funções
>
> b. uma função “insere caractere”. Ela deve solicitar o caractere ao usuário, e inserir no vetor, na primeira posição vazia, se ainda tiver espaço. Deve retornar se foi inserido ou não.
>
> c. Uma função “troca caractere”. Essa função solicita um novo caractere ao usuário. A função deve procurar no vetor o primeiro caractere que é maior que o caractere informado, quando achar, fazer
>   a troca. A função deve retornar se houve a troca ou não. Quando houver a troca, a função principal (main) deve ser capaz de imprimir qual foi o caractere que saiu do vetor.
>
> d. Uma função para remover caracteres. A remoção deve ser lógica, no final do vetor. Basta nesse caso decrementar o topo.
>
> e. Uma função para listar os caracteres.
>
> f. uma função que imprime cada um dos caracteres distintos e a quantidade de vezes que ele aparece no vetor

Estou tentando criar esse programa em C dá questão acima, mas estou tendo problemas em conseguir passar o sinalizador de volta para a main, o caractere retorna no ponto 0 do array, mas o flag não retorna como 1.

Esse foi o código que escrevi até o momento.

```
void insere(int array[],int n, int flag);

int main(){
    int array[10], n=0, flag=0;

    insere(array, n, flag);
    printf("%d", flag);
    if(flag==1){
        printf("numero inserido");
    }
    return 0;
}

void insere(int array[], int n, int flag){
    int i;

    printf("insira um numero: ");
    for(i=n; n<10; n++){
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    flag =1;
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da maneira como você definiu sua função o parâmetro `flag` está sendo passado por valor, isto é, uma cópia do valor existente na main é copiado para a pilha e qualquer modificação feita na função é feita exclusivamente na pilha e não na variável existente na main. Para o que deseja você precisa utilizar a passagem de parâmetro por referência.

Teste da seguinte forma:

```
void insere(int array[],int n, int *flag);

int main(){
    int array[10], n=0, flag=0;

    insere(array, n, &flag);
    printf("%d", flag);
    if(flag==1){
        printf("numero inserido");
    }
    return 0;
}
void
void insere(int array[], int n, int *flag){
    int i;

    printf("insira um numero: ");
    for(i=n; n<10; n++){
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    *flag = 1;
}
```

Se a função é `void` não tem sentido retornar um valor.

Ao passar o parâmetro por referência o valor que é colocado na pilha é o endereço da variável e neste caso quando você se refere ao conteúdo apontado por este endereço, isto é uma indireção, e então estará alterando o valor da variável definida na main.